# What does the word 'Avernus' mean in Carmilla by Sheridan Le Fanu?

Tags: meaning, sheridan-le-fanu, carmilla

[*Carmilla*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/10007) by Sheridan Le Fanu, Chapter 7:

> The first change I experienced was rather agreeable. It was very near the turning point from which began the descent of Avernus.

On Wikipedia it says Avernus is an ancient name for a [crater in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avernus), but that doesn't seem to fit exactly. I looked it up on [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Avernus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAvernus%3B%2Cc0) too:

[image: Google Ngram Viewer result for "Avernus" in the range 1800–2000]

The word was very common in the 19th century. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: For those of us who aren't familiar with the book, why doesn't the common ordinary meaning "descent of Avernus" = "descent into hell" seem to fit exactly?

Comment: @user14111 For those of us who aren't familiar with the phrase, I guess *"descent into Avernus" = "descent into hell"* answers this question perfectly :-)

Comment: The same, short, Wikipedia article says "Avernus was believed to be the entrance to the underworld. ... In later times, the word was simply an alternate name for the underworld."

Comment: @Randal'Thor [*Facilis descensus averno*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilis%20descensus%20Averno). "Avernus" is a headword in [*The Devil's Dictionary*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/972) by [Ambrose Bierce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrose_Bierce).

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: "Descent of Avernus" is an allusion to Virgil's *Aeneid*. In context in *Carmilla*, where the narrator Laura is describing her slide into a mysterious illness or ‘fascination’, it has the implication that it will be easy for her to succumb to the malady and difficult for her to escape.

The *Oxford Classical Dictionary* says:

> Avernus, a deep volcanic crater, now a lake, near Puteoli. Its appearance inspired the belief that it led to the Underworld.

In book VI of [Virgil's *Aeneid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneid), the Trojan prince [Aeneas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneas) visits the Underworld to speak with his dead father Anchises. The [Cumaean Sybil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumaean_Sibyl) had previously warned him that the Underworld is easy to enter but hard to leave:

> Tros Anchisiade, **facilis descensus Averni**;
>   noctes atque dies patet atri ianua Ditis;
>   sed revocare gradum superasque evadere ad auras,
>   hoc opus, hic labor est.

Roughly:

> Trojan, son of Anchises, **the descent of Avernus is easy**;
>   Night and day the dismal doors of [Dis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABs_Pater) stand open;
>   But to reclimb the stair and escape to the breezes above,
>   That is toil, that is labour.

(Some manuscripts of the *Aeneid* have *descensus Averno*, the descent *into* Avernus.)

This is one of the most well-known passages in the *Aeneid*, and *the descent of Avernus* is widely used to mean that it is easy to slide into evil or into disaster, and hard to get out again.

The decline in frequency of "Avernus" in the Google Ngram results is just a consequence of the general decline of classical reference. In the 19th century, the Greek and Latin classics were a pillar of the education of the middle and upper classes, hence a natural source of allusions and quotations. Not so much now.

Answer (score 4):

The crater [Avernus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avernus), outside [Cumae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumae), was thought by the Romans to be an entrance to the underworld where souls spent the afterlife. Aeneas visits it in Virgil's *The Aeneid*:

> Till, coming where Avernus, dark as night,
>   Gapes, with rank vapours from its depths uprolled.
>   <sub>*The Aeneid*, Book Six, XXVIII [Translation E. Fairfax Taylor](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/18466/18466-h/18466-h.htm)</sub>

Thus, "descent of Avernus" means a descent into the afterlife. In later, Christian contexts, the Roman afterlife was thought of as a version of Hell (not that strange; the word "hell" is the same as one of the places the Norse dead dwelt. Remember also that Virgil is Dante's guide through Hell in *Divina Commedia*). So, "descent of Avernus" is here equivalent to "road to Hell".